# How to clear a memory leak in BSTR

Tags: c++, memory

When running my application, it has a memory growth. So I collected UMDH data and it points to the below code,

```
BSTR bstrTestName = strCurTestName.AllocSysString();
 BSTR bstrTestInstname = strTestInstName.AllocSysString();
HRESULT hr = g_pDLServiceNetInterop->SetCurTestName(bstrTestName, pCurTestData->GetTestType(), bstrTestInstname, pCurTestData->GetTestMemberCount());
```

where strCurTestName and strTestInstName are `TString`.

I don't see a call to SysFreeString in this method.

I know that if we pass a BSTR to a client, it will take care of clearing the memory. In the current scenario, is this a leak and I need to call SysFreeString or it is not a leak.

Answer (score 2):

It is a leak. We need to explicitly clear it. Instead of BSTR, I used CComBSTR and it resolved the leak (yes, calling SysFreeString also resolved the leak).

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `SysFreeString(bstrTestName)` function to deallocate the string.

Edit:
as pointed out by the comment, since you are not passing the string to the client, just like with any allocated memory, it will stay allocated unless you free it with a the SysFreeString function call.

Comment: I think the question is whether OP should need to do that, or whether the COM method they're calling ought to take ownership of the string and free it.

Comment: Yes, I do pass the string to the client, but I am not passing as a reference or pointer. So I am not sure whether we need to explicitly clear it or automatically the COM method will take the ownership to clear it.